# SQL query to obtain customers with more than one ticket

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

Here is the schema:

```
 tblCustomers{custid,fname,lname,email}
 tblTicket{ticketId,custid,numOfPassengers,dateofJourney,totafare,trainId}
```

The problem query is: display all the customers who have booked more than one ticket. I am using Oracle 9. There is a foreign key between custid of both tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This?

```
SELECT C.custid
FROM tblCustomers C
  JOIN tblTickets T
    ON C.custid = T.custid
GROUP BY C.custid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If you want to have all fields from tblCustomers use this:

```
SELECT C.custid,C.fname,C.lname,C.email
FROM tblCustomers C
  JOIN tblTickets T
    ON C.custid = T.custid
GROUP BY C.custid,C.fname,C.lname,C.email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

or

```
SELECT
       C.custid,
       MAX(C.fname) as fname,
       MAX(C.lname) as lname,
       MAX(C.email) as email
FROM tblCustomers C
  JOIN tblTickets T
    ON C.custid = T.custid
GROUP BY C.custid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Do we have to apply join if custid of those two tables are already linked by foreign key?

Comment: You must read about referential integrity. `foreign key` tells to engine only about referential integrity.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  * 
from    tblCustomers 
where   custid in (select custid from tblTicket group by custid having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: If you just want the id of the customers then Hamlet's answer is best.  If you want to see the customer details as well then this will do that for you.

Comment: yep this also works only that it should be tblTicket in the nested query instead of tblCustomers.

Comment: @Mahesha999 Minor detail :)